# Android: Tracking mouse pointer movement

Tags: android, mouse, mouseevent, motion-detection

Assuming that I am using a generic mouse, is it possible to track the X and Y coordinates of the mouse pointer in android?

Answer (score 10):

You need a `OnGenericMotionListener`:

```
OnGenericMotion(...., MotionEvent me) {
if (me.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE) {

}
```

api `14+` needed
[confirmed] Found me a tablet with usb mouse and can confirm this works for mouse movement. You WILL get flooded with messages, so simple operations or sleeping should be considered.

Comment: `View.OnGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event)` is available starting with api level 12: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnGenericMotionListener.html#onGenericMotion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnGenericMotionListener.html#onGenericMotion)

Comment: Hmm in my case i attached it to a webview and I only get events when I click on the left mouse button...

Answer (score 0):

The docs to [ACTION_MOVE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MOVE) lead me to think that only drag events would be reported:

> Constant for getAction(): A change has
>   happened during a press gesture
>   (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).
>   The motion contains the most recent
>   point, as well as any intermediate
>   points since the last down or move
>   event.

Comment: Thank so much for your insight Matthew. I've also read about that. I think what I need to know if there is any way to track the mouse movement without having an ACTION_DOWN MotionEvent?

Comment: Do you have an Android device that has a mouse? If so you could test this out. I wasn't aware that there were any with mice.

Comment: Yeah, I actually have an android tablet that can use a mouse through USB port. Also, I already have a method using ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, and ACTION_DOWN and yes, they are working fine. But is there any way to have an ACTION_MOVE event for a mouse pointer without having an ACTION_DOWN first?

Comment: Hi. I'm facing the same problem. Save you found a way to track the mouse movements. I heard that it is possible to get the mouse movements using Internal classes, but not easy.

Comment: does any one know how to use mouse from other system i.e mouse is connected to my laptop and laptop and tablet are connected using wi-fi direct.Now i want to use mouse in tablet..

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `OnGenericMotion` solution did not work but attaching an `OnHoverListener` to the main view did the trick.