# Libgdx getting mouse position in android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a game that's running on ouya. I want to make a game object follow the cursor, but mouseMoved() only gets called in the desktop version of libgdx. Similarly, Gdx.input.getX() and getY() only update when the mouse is clicked (ouya touchpad tapped).

badlogic recommends using their controller api over the official ouya one for various reasons, and it works perfectly with everything else. Is there a way for libgdx to return the cursor position in android? I really want to avoid rewriting all my other controls when the libgdx controller extension works in every other aspect and supports multiple controllers. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you're ok with a joystick-controlled cursor, you could update its position through one of the controller listener methods like axisMoved(). You could try seeing if [touchDragged()](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling), the method used for touch screen devices, is called on the ouya, but I'm not sure if it will do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a non-OUYA approach. I can plug a USB mouse and keyboard into my phone using a USB adapter and I can pair a bluetooth mouse with my phone too. In fact you have to do this with a lot those HDMI android pc on a stick things. A mouse should cause all the touch events you normally detect in LibGDX but I think the OUYA touchpad functions a mouse so if you want to track it like a regular mouse you should be able to.

If you look at how the [Android backend](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java) and [PC backend](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglInput.java) are implemented you'll see that `getX` and similar query the mouse on PC but return the last stored touch location on android. But starting in Honeycomb you can get the cursor position with `View.OnGenericMotionListener` (see [Android: Tracking mouse pointer movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454448/android-tracking-mouse-pointer-movement)).

So you can add in some android specific (but not OUYA specific) code to track the cursor position.
Oh, and Android 4 added even more mouse related support - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I was thinking I'd have to do, but I'm not really sure how to implement android-specific api calls in my core libgdx project. But I'm sure I can figure it out with a little research. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while and you probably figured out how to do it, but I just wanted to let you know that I've submitted a patch to libGDX that allows for mouse tracking in the same way you do it on the desktop.

It's now done natively, starting with libGDX 1.4.1