# Tracking mouse cursor android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, mouseevent

I have a bluetooth mouse connected to my phone (galaxy s2, Android 4.1). I'm trying to get the cursor position and display it in a TextView using the OnHoverListener:

```
private class MouseListener implements View.OnHoverListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        String position = motionEvent.getX() + "  " + motionEvent.getY();
        mousePosition.setText(position);

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is set on a RelativeLayout:

```
layout.setOnHoverListener(new MouseListener());
```

The problem is that it only updates when I click and not when I move the mouse.

Comment: See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454448/android-tracking-mouse-pointer-movement

Comment: I tried that too but it did the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. I tried it with another mouse and it works.